# Ошибка при попытке распарсить request в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, request, response

В коде необходимо загрузить данные get методом и распарсить ответ(данные поступают в виде xml), что я собственно и сделал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И все шло гладко - получался валидный обьект ElementTree.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но стоит только вызвать свойство text из реквеста - сразу все сыпется и инфа не может быть распарсена.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код :

```
    import requests as re
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    USER = "XXX"
    PASSWD = "XXX"
    BASE_COPERNICUS_URL = "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s3/odata/v1/"
    try:
        http_resp = re.get(metadata_url, auth=(self.USER, self.PASSWD), stream=True)
        print(http_resp.text)
        http_resp.raw.decode_content = True
        xml_tree = ET.parse(http_resp.raw)
    except Exception as error:
        print("SMTH goes bad")
        print(error.__str__())
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код текстом, а не скриншотами...

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе содержимое переменной `metadata_url`?

Comment: На Вашем бы месте я не публиковал так открыто пароли (=

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените ВСЕ картинки на текст.

Comment: А зачем `raw`? Вы хотите руками разбирать gzip-ованый контент, передачу чанками?

Answer (score 0):

Выполните следующий код, заменив USER и PASSWD на валидные значения, то всё отработает корректно:

```
import requests

USER = "XXX"
PASSWD = "XXX"
BASE_COPERNICUS_URL = "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s3/odata/v1/"
try:
    http_resp = requests.get(BASE_COPERNICUS_URL, auth=(USER, PASSWD), stream=True)
    print(http_resp.text)
except Exception as error:
    print("SMTH goes bad")
    print(error.__str__())
```

Comment: Это да пока не приступаю к xml парсингу все идет отлично

Comment: @СанекТарасов Что за пакет ET? Приведите полный код

Comment: @hedgehogues, а зачем указывать `stream=True`?

Comment: @gil9red я сходу не помню. Кажется, что это не важный параметр